# Husky v5 doesn't create Git hooks

Tags: git, husky

I've installed Husky v5 in my application and I would like to run the `lint-staged` command upon commiting.

I've followed the [Getting Started](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/) docs but no .git/hooks/pre-commit file has been created in my git configuration files.

So, when I commit, the hook is not ran and the commit passes straight away without being checked by lint-staged.

I tried running `yarn add -D husky@next` or `npm i -D husky@next`.
I also tried removing node_modules and npm rebuild.

*.husky/pre-commit*

```sh
#!/bin/sh
[ -z "$CI" ] && exit 0

. "$(dirname $0)/_/husky.sh"

lint-staged
```

*package.json*

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "husky install"
},
```

Comment: the same is with husky 7.0.4

Comment: For `7.0.4` I did `npx husky install` just like it asked and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

husky v5 does not generates hooks (can not say why)
so I downgraded to 4.3.8 and removed .git/hooks(not necessary):

```
rm -rf .git/hooks
yarn add -D husky@4.3.8
```

Comment: Can confirm. With `husky@5.0.9` the git hooks folder was not being created and when committing it was complaining `husky-run` couldn't be found. Downgrading to `husky@4.3.8` worked.

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but I had this problem today too. After much searching I found [this issue](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/84) which describes installation problems involving Yarn. In my case yarn was not properly running the post-install script from husky and as advised on that thread I found changing my `postinstall` line in `package.json` to this solved my problem:

```json
{
    "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/husky/lib/installer/bin install"
}
```

I was running and re-running installation several times from various locations while finalising my setup. I found [this list](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/326#issuecomment-481260801) of instructions helpful in making sure I was resetting my git config to a consistent state each time, in particular the line mentioning `hooksPath`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add `yarn` before `lint-staged` in your `.husky/pre-commit` file:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
[ -z "$CI" ] && exit 0

. "$(dirname $0)/_/husky.sh"

yarn lint-staged
```

That's because of:

> If you were calling directly locally installed binaries, you need to
> **run them via your package manager**

More info you could find [here](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/618#issuecomment-737147267) and [here](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=locally-installed-binaries). Hope that helps